# Adding parameters to Select query in Code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to fill a GridView with data from a database and let the user choose what part of the "Cursussen" Table is shown. He can do this by changing the selection of the parameter in a dropdownbox.

**Error :** 
No overload for method "Add" takes 2 arguments.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConnectionStringSettings planner =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CursusDatabase"];
    DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(planner.ConnectionString);
    DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText =
        "SELECT * FROM Cursussen " +
        "WHERE CursusId = @CursusId";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("CursusId", DropDownList1.SelectedValue); // <-- here

    connection.Open();
    DbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable planning = new DataTable();
    planning.Load(rdr);
    connection.Close();

    GridView1.DataSource = planning;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT:

As specified by Oded in the comments, I missed that you are using DbCommand

```
var parameter = cmd.CreateParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "CursusId";
parameter.Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Comment: Which will not work, as OP is using `DbConnection` and `DbCommand` and not `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

Comment: Should i use Sqlconnection and command instead of dbconnection?

Comment: Okey will try get back to you in a sec

Comment: Got it working with the SqlConnection and the DbConnection. The reason why it took so long was because i had ORDER BY before WHERE :p

Answer (score 0):

You are using `DbCommand` - if you change this to be `SqlCommand`, you can do the following:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CursusId", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

Otherwise, you need to use the `Add` method that takes a `DbParameter`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new DbParameter { ParameterName = "CursusId", 
                                     Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myParamList As New List(Of SqlParameter)()
Dim myParam As SqlParameter = Nothing

myParam = New SqlParameter("@X", SqlDbType.Int)
myParam.Value = Y
myParamList.Add(myParam)
```

Then add the parameter list to the command.